# Когда я пытаюсь выбрать любой класс, мне вылезает ошибка: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'health'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
#  Hero Classes  #
class warrior(object):
    """Also Good class"""
    health = 175
    magic = 1
    defence = 10
    strenght = 10
class wizard(object):
    """ITS IMBA!"""
    health = 170
    magic = 10
    defence = 7
    strenght = 7
class archer(object):
    """Good class for beginners"""
    health = 130
    strenght = 5
    defence = 5
    magic = 3
class Sanirar(object):
    """Живёт в Дурке"""
    health = 175
    magic = 3
    defence = 6
    strenght = 7
#  Enemy Classes  #
class Koronavirus(object):
    name = "Коронавирус"
    health = 20
    strenght = 3
    defence = 3
    loot = random.randint(0,2)
class GoblinArcher(object):
    name = "Гоблин-Лучник"
    health = 23
    strenght = 4
    defence = 4
    loot = random.randint(0,2)
class MiniBoss(object):
    name = "Большой Троль"
    health = 35
    strenght = 10
    defence = 7
def SelectHero():
    selection = input("Выберите своего героя \n 1.Воин. \n 2.Маг. \n 3.Санитар. \n 4.Лучник\n")
    if(selection == '1'):
        character = warrior 
        print('Нормальный класс')
        print('health -', character.health)
        print('magic -', character.magic) 
        print('defence -', character.defence)
        print('strenght -', character.strenght)
        return character
        return character
    if(selection == '2'):
        character = wizard
        print('ИМБА!')
        print('health -', character.health)
        print('magic -', character.magic) 
        print('defence -', character.defence)
        print('strenght -', character.strenght)
        return character
    if(selection == '3'):
        character = Санитар
        print('Hey it is DLC Character')
        print('В ДУРКУ!!!!')
        print('health -', character.health)
        print('magic -', character.magic) 
        print('defence -', character.defence)
        print('strenght -', character.strenght)
        return character
    if(selection == '4'):
        character = "Лучник"
        print('Good Class For Beginners')
        print('health -', character.health)
        print('magic -', character.magic) 
        print('defence -', character.defence)
        print('strenght -', character.strenght)
        return character
    else:
        print('Please click on only one, two, three or four')
        SelectHero()
SelectHero()
def enemyselect(GoblinArcher,Koronavirus):
    enemylist = [GoblinArcher,Koronavirus]
    chance = random.randint(0,1)
    enemy = enemylist[chance]
    return enemy

def loot():
    loot = ['potion','sword','shield']
    lootChance = random.randint(0,2)
    lootDrop = loot[lootChance]
    return lootDrop
def battlestate():
    enemy = enemyselect(GoblinArcher, Koronavirus)
    print("A Wild", enemy.name, "has appeared!")
    print('You Have 3 options...')
    while enemy.health > 0:
        choise = input("1.Sword\n 2.Magic \n 3.Run!\n")
        if choise == '1':
            print('You Swing your Sword and attack', enemy.name)
            hitchance = random.randint(0,10)
            if hitchance > 3:
                enemy.health = enemy.health - character.strenght
                print("You hit the", enemy.name)
battlestate()
```

Comment: LOL, а что вы хотите сделать? Нет, можно в Питоне и с *классами* работать, а не их *экземплярами*, но всё же...

Comment: Смотри `def list_supported_services: for attr in dir(self.module): if attr.endswith('Service') and attr != 'Service':  yield attr.replace('Service', '')` — это функция генератора, которая ищет атрибут (или в нашем случае *класс*) по суффиксу в имени.

Comment: А вот это создаёт *экземпляр* класса, который мы нашли выше `for srv in self.list_supported_services(): if srv.lower() == name.lower(): return getattr(self.module, srv + "Service")()`.

Comment: Вот переделай так, питонично, модно, молодёжно будет!

Comment: Вот забыл: `self.module = sys.modules[globals()['__name__']]` для дополнения к вышеприведенному.

Comment: Вот тут нечто подобное сделано: http://web.mit.edu/6.034/www/labs/lab2/tester.py В общем, гуглите

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло!